# Decomposing input to two list

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation, code-request

Suppose I have $j[1,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5]$, I want to extract this as $\{1,\{a1,a2,a3,a4,a5\}\}$.

--My first trial:

Using the command Split, I can make

```
 Split[List @@ j[1, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5]]


 {{1}, {a1}, {a2}, {a3}, {a4}, {a5}}
```

Which is not desired form.

-- Second trial

Let

```
 aa= List @@ j[1, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5] 

 bb= List @@ j[1, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5] // Delete[1]

 List[aa[[1]],bb]
```

It seems to work but is there any more simplified version?

Comment: Try:  `j[1, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5] /. j[x1_, x2__] -> {x1, x2}`

Comment: `{#, {##2}} & @@ j[1, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5]`

Comment: I can also think of: `{First[aa], Rest[aa] /. j -> List}` or `FlattenAt[TakeDrop[aa, 1] /. j -> List, 1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Replace[j[1,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5], j[x_,y__]:> {x,{y}}]

(* {1, {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5}} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this using `GroupBy`:

```
aa = List @@ j[1, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5];

Values@GroupBy[aa, SameQ[Head[#], Symbol] &, 
If[!ContainsOnly[Head[#] & /@ #, {Symbol}], First@#, #] &]

(*{1, {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5}}*)
```